# How does a MySQL connection pool distinguish between connections in NodeJS (using mysqljs)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, google-cloud-sql

I've read all of the pooling documentation from mysqljs and I'm still missing some context. My CloudSQL bill just came back and reminded me that my old method is severely flawed. I'm looking for some context around how to handle MySQL pooling in NodeJS for a CRM that makes a ton of SQL queries.

**My Old Connection Method:**

```
//* SELECT BY ID
app.post(`/api/v1/select/id`, (req, res) => {
  let did = req.body.did;
  let host = req.body.host;
  let user = req.body.user;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let schema = req.body.schema;
  let columns = accountColumns();
  let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: schema,
    port: 3306,
  });
  if (connection.state === "disconnected") {
    connection.connect();
  }
  let selectStatement = `SELECT * FROM mydb.schema WHERE id = ${did};`;
  connection.query(selectStatement, (err, results) => {
    if (err) { throw err }
    else {
    res.send(results);
    }
  });
});

//* SELECT BY STATUS
app.post('/api/v1/status', (req, res) => {
  let status= req.body.status;
  let host = req.body.host;
  let user = req.body.user;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let schema = req.body.schema;
  let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: schema,
    port: 3306,
  });
  if (connection.state === "disconnected") {
    connection.connect();
  }
  let selectStatement= `SELECT * FROM mydb.schema WHERE status = ${status};`;
  connection.query(selectStatement, (err, results) => {
    if (err) { throw err }
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json({ results });
    } 
  });
});
```

**The Problem:**

- I just got a $200 GCP cloud SQL bill from 3 weeks of minimal testing
- Connections are being opened and closed every time an endpoint is hit (which can be hundreds of time per user per hour
- It worked on a small scale and with a VPS but this isn't sustainable with GCP Cloud SQL

**The New Approach:**

Implement pooling so that there won't be such absurd overhead associated with constantly connecting.

```
//* CREATE CONNECTION
let getConnection = (host, user, password, database) => {
let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit:10,
    host: host,
    user: user,
    password: password,
    database: database
})
  return pool
}

// Testing the initial connection
app.get('/test/:host/:user/:password/:database', (req, res) => {
  let pool = getConnection(req.params.host, req.params.user, req.params.password, req.params.database)
  pool.getConnection((err, db) => {
    if (err) { throw err }
    else {
      db.query('SELECT * FROM mydb.schema LIMIT 10;', (queryErr, records) => {
        if (queryErr) { throw queryErr }
        else {
          res.send(records)
        }
        db.release() //? do I release it if I know it will continue to be used?
      })
    }
  })
})

// This endpoint will be hit hundreds of times per session. Trying to see if the original connection will carry over without having to reconnect with the config data again
//? Would I need a try catch block here?
app.get('/test2/:host/:user/:password/:database', (req, res) => {
  let pool = getConnection(req.params.host, req.params.user, req.params.password, req.params.database)
  pool.getConnection((err, db) => {
    if (err) { throw err }
    else {
      db.query('SELECT * FROM mydb.schema LIMIT 10;', (queryErr, records) => {
        if (queryErr) { throw queryErr }
        else {
          res.send(records)
        }
        db.release() //? do I release it if I know it will continue to be used?
      })
    }
  })
})
```

- Is there any risk of user A getting data from user B's database if I rely on pooling?
- How does the pool recognize the connection that is being requested?
- If there isn't currently an open pool, will it default to creating one? Do I need to make a try/catch block to make sure that happens?
- Is this syntax correct?
- If the 'test2' endpoint is hit hundreds of times, is this a reasonable way to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

A connection pool is a cache of database connections that are shared and reused to improve connection latency and performance. When you app needs a database connection, it would borrow one from it's pool temporaily. When you app is finished with the connection, it would return the connection back to the pool, where is could be resused the next time your app needs a connection to the database. I would recommend you take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#pools) for more details.

Cloud SQL does not automatically provide or configure load balancing for your database instance. You would need to set up connection pooling to distribute read/write requests for databases between multiple connection points.

If you are looking to make multiple requests to an endpoint, it's recommended to implement a [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#backoff) strategy as it prevents your app from sending an unresponsive number of connection requests when it can't connect to your database. However, in your case, for node.js the mysql module automatically uses exponential delays between failed connection attempts.

Regarding, the risk of data access from various users of your database. I would suggest you have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/users), as it describes how Cloud SQL works with MySQL users.